# Square payment processing receipt_url is invalid

Tags: square

I've created a Square sandbox web app that collects the credit card, sends to processing, and receives a successful JSON string in return.
One of the JSON objects is "receipt_url" which returns a URL to what I assume is the payment receipt. In my sandbox app, the URL never works. The page says "The page you are looking for canʼt be found."
Should this be working in the sandbox or am I misinterpreting something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no receipts in the sandbox: https://www.sellercommunity.com/t5/E-Commerce-API/Are-receipts-supposed-to-work-for-sandbox-payments/m-p/162597